# Display SVN blame info when hover on line of code in VS2013

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, visualsvn

Earlier I had used eclipse with CVS and could see CVS commit details (such as author, log message) when I hover on line of code. This is very helpful to visualize the history of code snippet and why it is there.

Presently I use Visual SVN with VS2013 and it supports blame which is similar to CVS annotate. But when I run SVN blame on VS2013 a pop up is opened with revision history. But I love to see the annotation details when I hover on a line of code. Can you please shed some light on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can contact support@visualsvn.com and file a feature request.

Comment: Thank you. I'll write up an email to them.